# SWIG - C++ code in python

Tags: python, c++, python-import, swig, importerror

I tried to import the SWING generated module, but I got an ImportError:

```
>>> import ava
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ava.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ava = swig_import_helper()
  File "ava.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_ava', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: ./_ava.so: undefined symbol: _Z7turn_aiPPiiii
>>>
```

I followed SWIG's tutorial (http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) and I compiled my main.cpp like this:

```
swig -python -c++ ava.i
c++ -fPIC -c ava_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7/
c++ -shared ava_wrap.o -o _ava.so
```

and I tried to extern my functions to c:

```
extern "C" {
  bool isEnd(int** t, int x, int y, int K, int J);
  void tout(int** t, int K);
  koord turn(int** t, int player, int K, int J);
  koord turn_ai(int** t, int player, int K, int J);
  bool isPat(int** t, int K);
  ai_res turn_ai_3x3_v2(int** t, int turn);
  ai_res turn_ai_pre(int** t, int turn, int K, int J, int dep);
  ai_res turn_ai_(int** t, int turn, int K, int J, int ab, int dep);
  bool isSeparated(int** t, int K, int i, int j);
  std::vector<koord> stepsFun(int** t, int K);
  bool isEmpty(int** t, int K);
  int value(int** t, int K);
  int fofug();
}
```

Comment: Now I modified my ava.i from
`/* ava.i */
%module ava
%{
    /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
    #include "koord.h"
    extern koord turn_ai(int** t, int player, int K, int J);
%}

%include "koord.h"
extern koord turn_ai(int** t, int player, int K, int J);`
to 
`/* ava.i */
%module ava
%{
    /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
    #include "koord.h"
    extern "C" koord turn_ai(int** t, int player, int K, int J);
%}

%include "koord.h"
extern "C" koord turn_ai(int** t, int player, int K, int J);`

Comment: But it's still the same error, just the end is now `undefined symbol: turn_ai`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `c++` commands. Your `_ava.so` contains the SWIG wrappers, but is missing the implementations for `turn_ai` etc.

Look carefully at the SWIG Tutorial, there are `example.c` and `example.o` which contain implementations of `fact`, `my_mod`, etc.